# Two-point function of operators with different scaling dimension on a disk

Tags: operators, conformal-field-theory, correlation-functions

[This paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2111.06298)'s equation (2.39) says
$$ 
\left\langle \sigma(z, \overline{z}) O(y)\right\rangle_{\text{disk}} \propto  \frac{(1-|z|^2)^{h_b - 2h}}{|1-z\overline{y}|^{2 h_b}}
$$
where $h, h_b$ are scaling dimensions of $\sigma$ and $O$ respectively. Here the operator $O(y)$ is on the boundary of the disk.

I've been trying to prove it, but have been unsuccessful so far. Here is my attempt.

---

**Steps.**

1. Conformally transform the above to a function on UHP.
2. Use doubling trick for UHP function to get it on $\mathbb{C}$

**Step 1. Jacobian factors**

Conformal transformation modifies [See Ginsparg for example] correlation functions as
$$ 
\langle \phi_1(x_1) \phi_2(x_2) \rangle = \left| \frac{\partial x'}{\partial x} \right|_{x_1}^{\Delta_1/d}  \left| \frac{\partial x'}{\partial x} \right|_{x_2}^{\Delta_2/d} \langle \phi_1 (x_1')\phi_2(x_2') \rangle 
$$
where the prefactors are Jacobians. Here $x \to z$  and $x'\to w$. Then
$$ 
\langle \sigma(z_1) O(z_2) \rangle = \left| \frac{\partial w}{\partial z} \right|_{z_1}^{h/2}  \left| \frac{\partial w}{\partial z} \right|_{z_2}^{h_b/2} \langle \sigma (w_1) O(w_2) \rangle 
$$
Here $z_1, z_2, w_1, w_2$ are actually doublets, like $z_1, \overline{z}_1$, etc.

We need the Jacobian of transformation $z, \overline{z} \to  w, \overline{w}$:
$$ 
\left|\frac{\partial w}{\partial z} \right| = \frac{\partial w}{\partial z} \frac{\partial \overline{w}}{\partial \overline{z}} 
$$
I've verified that the map from UHP to disk is,
$$ 
z= \frac{i - w}{i+w} 
$$
where $w, z$ are coordinates for plane and disk respectively, which gives
$$ 
w = i \left(\frac{1-z}{1+z}\right)
$$
$$
\frac{\partial w}{\partial z}= i \left(- \frac{2}{\left(z + 1\right)^{2}}\right), \quad \frac{\partial \overline{w}}{\partial \overline{z}}= -i \left(- \frac{2}{\left(\overline{z} + 1\right)^{2}}\right)
$$
so Jacobian is
$$ 
\frac{4}{|z+1|^2} 
$$
and
$$ 
\langle \sigma(z_1) O(z_2) \rangle = \left(\frac{2}{|z_1+1|}\right)^{h} \left(\frac{2}{|z_2+1|}\right)^{h_b}   \langle \sigma (w_1) O(w_2) \rangle_{UHP}
$$
**Step 2.**

Let's place $w_2$ on the boundary, i.e. $\overline{w}_2 = w_2$, and we get
$$ 
\left\langle \sigma(w_1) O(w_2)\right\rangle_{\text{UHP}} = \left\langle \sigma(w_1) O(w_2) \sigma(\overline{w}_1)\right\rangle_{\mathbb{C}}
$$
$$
=  \frac{(w_1 - \overline{w}_1)^{h_b -2 h}}{[(w_1 - w_2) (\overline{w}_1 - w_2)]^{h_b}}
$$
Here I'm using the three point formula while assuming I don't need to take mod signs because this is a "chiral theory" (?) Next, I need to substitute
$$ 
w_k = i \left( \frac{1 - z_k}{ 1 + z_k}\right) , \quad k =1,2
$$
and then $z_2 \to y$. Substituting gives

$$ 
 \left(\frac{i{\left(- 2 z \overline{z} + 2 \right)}}{|1+z|^2}\right)^{- 2 h + h_{b}} \left(- \frac{4 y^{2} \overline{z} - 4 y z \overline{z} - 4 y + 4 z}{\left(y + 1\right)^{2} |1+z|^2}\right)^{- h_{b}}
$$
$$
\propto { {\left(1-|z|^2\right)}}^{- 2 h + h_{b}} \left( \frac{ y^{2} \overline{z} -  y z \overline{z} -  y +  z}{\left(y + 1\right)^{2}}\right)^{- h_{b}}
$$
So
$$ 
 \langle \sigma(z_1) O(y) \rangle \propto { {\left(1-|z|^2\right)}}^{- 2 h + h_{b}} \left( \frac{\left(y - z\right) \left(y \overline{z} - 1\right)}{\left(y + 1\right)^{2}}\right)^{- h_{b}}  \left(\frac{1}{|z+1|}\right)^{h} \left(\frac{1}{|y+1|}\right)^{h_b}
$$
$$
 = \frac{{\left(1-|z|^2\right)}^{- 2 h + h_{b}}}{( y \overline{z} - 1)^{h_b}} \left( \frac{\left(y + 1\right)} {\left(y - z\right) }\right)^{ h_{b}}  \left(\frac{1}{|z+1|}\right)^{h} \left(\frac{y+1}{|y+1|}\right)^{h_b}
$$
$$
\propto \frac{{\left(1-|z|^2\right)}^{- 2 h + h_{b}}}{( y \overline{z} - 1)^{h_b}} \left( \frac{y + 1} {\left(y - z\right) }\right)^{ h_{b}}  \left(\frac{1}{|z+1|}\right)^{h} 
$$
I've dropped the phase factor but I think this is wrong because there is a $|z+1|$ with power $h$.

Why isn't the result matching with theirs?